# Render template after executing all functions in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have following **Code**, which gets executed when someone is on the index page:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'tZAz6M'
});

connection.connect();
connection.query("USE BlogDB");

var network;

function query(sql, callback) {
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(rows);
        }
    });
}

query("SELECT * FROM TestTabelle", function(results){
    network = results;
    console.log("inside the query function " + network);
});

connection.end(function(err){});
console.log("outside the query function " + network);
res.render('index.hjs', { Mysql : network });
}
```

The template gets rendered seemingly before the query could even execute because the value 
in the query function is the result of the query and the result of the query outside the function is undefined. How can I make it possible that I **render the template after doing the query** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `res.render` inside the callback:

```
query("SELECT * FROM TestTabelle", function(results){
    network = results;
    console.log("inside the query function " + network);

    res.render('index.hjs', { Mysql : network });
});
```

Comment: Yeh I did that too and it worked, but I didn't expect that too be best practice. What if I wanted to add extra stuff to my code ?

Comment: For single cases this is ok. Otherwise the best solution is to use promises and wait till all promises resolve.

Comment: Okay so I will have a look at promises, since your answer is correct I will accept it.

Comment: @IbrahimApachi take a look at https://github.com/kriskowal/q (I personally like that one). And it's promises/A+ compliant